# How to make list of next and previous days table header with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

iam trying to make a html dynamic header with javascript to select all week days with date for next week and previous week.when button is press for next week table header change from this week to next week and when i click on button for prevoius week this should change the current week header with prevoius week and change all days.

[Here is a header picture which i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjnKn.png)

```
function days(current) {
  var week = new Array();
  // Starting Monday not Sunday 
  var first = ((current.getDate() - current.getDay()) + 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    week.push(
      new Date(current.setDate(first++))
    );
  }
  return week;
}

var input = new Date(2017, 1, 27);
console.log('input: %s', input);

var result = days(input);
console.log(result.map(d => d.toString()));
```

What iam getting at this time .

[array of on week all days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKuxX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is: `new Date(current.setDate(first++))`

It is first modifying `current` then creating a new Date from the modified current

Instead, create the new date from original `current` then modify that new date. This way `current` never changes.

```js
function days(current) {
  var week = new Array();
  // Starting Monday not Sunday 
  var first = ((current.getDate() - current.getDay()) + 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    // create clone of current
    const d = new Date(current);
    // now setDate without modifying current
    d.setDate(first + i)
    // and push to array
    week.push(d);
  }
  return week;
}

var input = new Date(2017, 1, 29);
console.log('input: %s', input);

var result = days(input);
console.log(result.map(d => d.toString()));
```